# More font colors for JS files in Visual Studio (Express 2013 for Web)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, fonts

I've just started learning Javascript and I was wondering if there is a way to get more colors for the code to improve learning? In the previous answers I found that keywords, identifiers, strings and comments can get unique colors, is it possible to get more? For example, this row is now all in one color except for the brackets, the 0 and the equal sign:

document.getElementById(rowId).cells[0].innerHTML = theText;

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById(rowId).cells[0].innerHTML = theText;
```

Unfortunately most of this cannot be changed. The alphabet text in your example all fall under the same category: Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Identifier. You can change the period in: Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Punctuation.